# Hide portion of a widget from author's own profile page - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a plugin called [Widget Logic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/).

On every author's page I added a contact me form, where you can send the author a message, but I want to hide it if the author is visiting his own profile page.
I see examples like !is_author(), but I don't know how to make the comparison.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this check with the `is_author()` function because:

> This Conditional Tag checks if an Author archive page is being displayed. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.

Of course you can use the `is_author()` to do the check on a higher level other than the theme template file `author.php`. For instance when using hooks. Then you could use it.

But I asume you are doing things in the template file, so what you are looking for is something like this:

```
$current_author = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
var_dump($current_author->ID); // < just for you to confirm what value it returns for the current profile you are on
var_dump(get_current_user_id()); // < just for you so you can see what the current user ID is of the user who is logged in at this moment
if( $current_author->ID!=get_current_user_id() ) {
    // Display the form...
}else{
    // Maybe do something else or do nothing...  
}
```

**Update (deregister widget when author ID is same as logged in user ID)**

In this example we deregister a Text widget by passing it's class `WP_Widget_Text` to the `unregister_widget()` function.

For a full list of WordPress widget class names refer to: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget

Put this in your theme `functions.php` file.

```
function riseagainst_remove_text_widget() {
    // Because `widget_init` is called early, we can not use `get_permalink()` 
    // neither can we use `home_url( $wp->request )`, neither can we get the
    // current author ID at this level when we are on profile page. And we
    // need to deregister the widget at this hook, and not at a later stage
    // otherwise it will simply override our deregister call to wordpress.
    // That's why we will use some of the `$_SERVER` array to obtain the current
    // URL (which is provided by the server upon requesting the page).
    // We only need the last part of the URL to check if we are on an author page.
    $page_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    // The last part of the URL is the author slug in case we are on the author
    // profile page. To get the last part of an URL we use `basename()`,
    // this will return the slug of the author
    $author_name = basename($page_url);

    // Now we have the author slug, we can retrieve all author information
    // We only need the author ID but this can also be used for other data
    // When plain permalink is enabled, we can not search based on slug,
    // Instead we will be provided with the author ID via the URL parameter
    // named `author`. So do a check on that first
    $current_author = ( isset($_GET['author']) ? get_user_by('id', absint($_GET['author'])) : get_user_by('slug', $author_name) );

    // This check is important to only execute the code whenever we actually
    // are on an author page, when no author was found, we are probably not
    // on an author page. (note that if you have problems with it, you can
    // also do a check on if the URL path contains `/author/`)
    if( $current_author ) {
        // Only display the widget whenever current author ID
        // is not equal to current logged in user ID
        if( $current_author->ID!=get_current_user_id() ) {
            // Display the widget...
        }else{
            // Do not display the widget...
            unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Text');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'riseagainst_remove_text_widget' );
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I know that does not work, I was wondering if that combined with something else would. I know next to nothing of php. I'm using a widget, as said in the question, which offers conditional logic with that plugin. Now, the form itself, added to the widget, does not display (it is coded like that) when the author views its own author page, but the widget does, and shows a blank div.

Comment: When looking through the documentation it states you can only use `Conditional Tags` meaning you could do like this: `is_author('4')` but of course number 4 must be replaced with the current logged in author ID. And this isn't possible with that plugin nor via conditional tags. So I am afraid it's not possible, maybe just modify the `author.php` it's much easier and possibly the only way. (unless you really don't want to touch any php files). Otherwise I would suggest to contact author instead and ask for such a feature.

Comment: Yeah I had read that already. I'm trying to hide the widget itself, hence the plugin.

Comment: if you want to hide contact form in case if author in logged in then you can do this by using if(is_user_logged_in()){  ......  } else {  ....... }

Comment: @RensTillmann If I add this code you provided, how would I hide the widget? Via its id? Sorry, I really know the bare minimum in php.

Comment: Ok, yes I will have to update the code. I will edit my current answer based on your needs. With a different approach. In this case you will be able to put the script inside your `functions.php` file of your theme.